# How to set price for using the OCR in Chainlink?

Tags: chainlink

**Where is the price per one request to an Offchain Aggregator price feed set?**

Is it in:

- the job .toml file via the Chainlink Node operator (type= "directrequest") in the form of `minContractPaymentLinkJuels = 1000000000000000000`
- or in the "getBilling" section of the AccessControlledOffchainAggregator
- or in the .env file of the node as "MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS"
- or somhwere else?

Answer (score 1):

To set up the job fee, add the next line to the job's `.toml` file:

```
minContractPaymentLinkJuels = <fee>
```

To set up fee on node globally, add the next line to the `.env` file:

```
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS = <fee>
```

Comment: Does this mean that the fee for using a price feed OCR is the sum of all global node fees set in the .env via MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS = <fee> ? For example: 5 nodes x 0.01 LINK = 0.05 LINK to use a price feed OCR with 5 nodes?